# How do I pass a Java String[] array as arguments to a translation in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use the #{} from Thymeleaf to translate a string and some arguments passed from my Spring Boot controller.

Currently I tried doing it like this:

```
<td th:text="#{__${notification.title}__(__${#strings.arrayToString(notification.titleArgs)}__)}"></td>
```

notification.title contains the string that corresponds with the value in messages.properties and notification.titleArgs is an array of Strings.
It generates this exception:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "#{**${notification.title}**(**${#strings.arrayToString(notification.titleArgs)}**)}" (template: "user-notifications" - line 18, col 29)
> at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:131) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:62) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:44) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.EngineEventUtils.parseAttributeExpression(EngineEventUtils.java:220) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.EngineEventUtils.computeAttributeExpression(EngineEventUtils.java:207) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:125) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.processIterationModel(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:368) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:222) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.CloseElementTag.beHandled(CloseElementTag.java:139) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1414) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1158) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1097) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
> at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
> at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]

Answer (score 0):

According to the reference here: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#strings

There are two options:

1 - use `${#strings.toString(obj)}` it will show string version of your array (maybe including the `[]` brackets of array)

2 - if you want to show the array with some join character like `,` use `${#strings.arrayJoin(namesArray,',')}`

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't tried Neenad's solution yet.

I solved it as follows:

```
<td th:text="#{__${notification.titleFull}__}"></td>
```

Where notification.titleFull = "translate.this(arg1, arg2)" as a String

I just haven't thought about it yet in this way.